# Balanced Gray codes for powers of 2

Tags: co.combinatorics, symmetry, gray-codes

All of the binary 4-bit cyclic balanced Gray code sequences can be formed from simple reversals, bit-permutations, and circular shifts of [the one Wikipedia example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code#Balanced_Gray_code):

```
toggle bit number:  0 1 0 2 0 3 2 1 2 3 0 3 1 2 1 3
```

Is this also true for 8 bits?  If not, what is the multiplicity?

I'd like to know the multiplicity for 256 bits also if that's easy.

Comment: crossposted -- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3688990/balanced-gray-codes-for-powers-of-2 -- please don't, to avoid wasteful duplication of efforts.

Comment: Ok, I'll delete the question from the "easy site", I copied it here because no one could answer it.

Comment: By the way, I don't actually need to include reversals above (since a 1-for-2 permutation gives the reversal). I'm curious about all symmetries, including this "reverse symmetry", for higher powers.

Comment: Please define the terms: simple reversals, bit-permutations, and multiplicity (of what?).